# INS-20802 Oracle Cluster Verification Utility failed

Tags: database, oracle, aix, oracle12c

I was trying to install Oracle 12cR1 RAC on a two-nodes AIX 7.2 cluster. Encountered this error when Installer performing Cluster Verification in the step 18/19.

[image: oracle cluster verification failed]

Last lines in log:

```
INFO: ERROR: 
INFO: Reference data is not available for release "12.1" on the operating system distribution "AIX7.2"
INFO: ERROR: 
INFO: Verification cannot proceed
INFO: Collecting OS best practice baseline
INFO: Collecting availability of port 8888 ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - ipqmaxlen ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - rfc1323 ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - sb_max ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - tcp_sendspace ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - tcp_recvspace ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - udp_sendspace ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network parameter - udp_recvspace ...collected
INFO: Collecting Ethernet Jumbo Frames ...collected
INFO: Collecting Clusterware mandatory requirements baseline
INFO: Collecting Node Connectivity ...collected
INFO: Collecting Multicast check ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Time zone consistency ...collected
INFO: Collecting Cluster Manager Integrity ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting User Mask ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Cluster Integrity ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting OCR Integrity ...collected
INFO: Collecting CRS Integrity ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Node Application Existence ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Single Client Access Name (SCAN) ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting OLR Integrity ...collected
INFO: Collecting Voting Disk ...collected
INFO: Collecting User Not In Group: grid ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Clock Synchronization ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting VIP Subnet configuration check ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Clusterware OHASD Resource Model Collection ...collected
INFO: Collecting Clusterware Resource Model Collection ...collected
INFO: Collecting GPnP Profile ...collected
INFO: Collecting Network configuration consistency checks ...nothing to collect
INFO: Collecting Software home: /opt/grid_home ...collected
INFO: Collecting Clusterware best practice baseline
INFO: Collecting CSS misscount parameter ...collected
INFO: Collecting CSS reboottime parameter ...collected
INFO: Collecting CSS disktimeout parameter ...collected
INFO: Baseline data collection failed.
INFO: Post-check for cluster services setup was unsuccessful on all the nodes. 
INFO: 
WARNING: 
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Cluster Verification Utility
```

With this error occured, RAC status seemed normal though:

```
bash-3.00# ./crsctl check crs
CRS-4638: Oracle High Availability Services is online
CRS-4537: Cluster Ready Services is online
CRS-4529: Cluster Synchronization Services is online
CRS-4533: Event Manager is online
```

Any ideas about how to fix this? is it okay to just ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is an Oracle bug related to the cvu_prereq.xml file. RE MOS Doc ID 2169858.1 simply verify that all your [pre-reqs are valid](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AXDBI/pre_install.htm#CIHEIAHI) then run the installer with the `ignoreSysPrereqs` flag.

```
/runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs
```